# What causes "Cannot connect to iTunes Store" using In-App purchases in an Ionic 3 app?

Tags: in-app-purchase, app-store-connect, ionic3, ios11, testflight

I wrote an Ionic 3 app for iOS and use the native in app purchase. I know, that in app purchase (IAP) is only working on a real device.

The problem is, that I submitted my app to Apple and they rejected the app because IAP isn't working. Only the error "Cannot connect to iTunes Stores" shows up.

And, of course, before I submitted my app to Apple I tested my app using TestFlight on multiple devices. And, what should I say, IAP works like a charm.

The problem now is that I can not reproduce this error. I wrote to Apple multiple times to get more info and explained that they have to test on a real device. The answer was every time the same. They are testing on an iPad using iOS 11.2. and so on.

So, here I am. Anybody experienced the same problem and was able to solve it? I've no clue what to do now. Are there other things that cause this error?

Thanks for your help,
Daniel